# Is there any single framework for writing iOS, Android (and even Windows Phone)?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, cross-platform

I would like to have a cross platform framework as these platform solutions. 
My application requires location service, socket programming, camera access and push notifications. So, the web app is not the way to go.... Is there any tools or framework to doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because you want to access platform-specific features such as camera, GPS, notifications etc., you're going to need to call platform-specific API's.

As such, at least SOME of your app code will need to be platform dependent. However, there's a good chance that a majority of your app's code & logic can be shared across multiple platforms. I would STRONGLY recommend Mono as a great multi-platform development environment. On Windows & Windows Phone, your code will run in .NET. For Linux & OSX, you can use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). For Android & iOS, you can use [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/)'s tools.

The key here though is that if you package your app logic into "Portable Assemblies" (i.e. assemblies which take dependencies on parts of the .NET framework available across all implementations of the CLI/CLR), then your code can generally run without modification on Windows, Windows Phone, Linux, OSX, Android and iOS!

All you need to do then is build platform-specific shells that make your app look like a platform-native app using the typical controls and design metaphors of the various platforms you want to support.

HTH.

***Update 2012-04-06**: If you want to take advantage of Portable Libraries, here is some [updated documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) that refer to the newly updated version of Portable Libraries included in the recently released (and well-worth-a-look) Visual Studio 11 Beta.*

***Update 2012-04-11**: A new article titled '[Create a Continuous Client Using Portable Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852593.aspx)' was published in the March 2012 edition of the MSDN Magazine that illustrates how to use PL's to create an app for Windows Phone and Windows 8 that share the same core business logic.*

Comment: I see. So, I need create something like a lib for general logic with little platform depends code....

Comment: Generally, it's a sound approach to separate your generic business logic into a reusable assembly which can then be consumed by platform-specific applications. This lets you achieve high levels of code-reuse without having to copy & paste and maintain code across multiple projects.

Answer (score 3):

http://phonegap.com/about is the best approximation I can provide.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not looking at web-apps, you might want to take a look at [codenameone](http://www.codenameone.com/index.html). It's `java` based and they have a plugin for `eclipse` too.

Answer (score 2):

The latest release of the [Qt Framework](http://qt.digia.com) (5.1) has what they call a "Technology Preview" of Android and iOS support. Fully released support will come in the soon to be released 5.2 version.

Given the extensive and successful history of Qt as a cross platform development framework I have high hopes for this. (Disclaimer: I have only used it for Win/Mac/Linux development so far...)

Answer (score 2):

For native cross-platform framework, you should check out [Crosslight](http://www.intersoftpt.com/crosslight). It currently supports apps development targeting iOS, Android, WP8 and Win8.

UPDATE: Crosslight includes built-in services that you're looking for, such as:

- Camera Services: Taking photo from camera, browse photo from gallery, retrieve cropped image, produce either full or thumbnail version
- Location Services: Get current location, get location by address, track location
- Notification Services: Schedule local notification service
- Connectivity Services: Check if an Uri is reachable, get current connection (WiFi or WWAN)
- Many other useful services such as mail services, browser services, map services, etc.

Comment: Crosslight looks pretty interesting, but the price is not small. $2K for a single developer license. Not an issue for many corporations, but for an indie developer that's prohibitive.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [Mono](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/)
Its a high-performance HTML5 mobile application framework. Works for iphone, android, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Mono

[Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [Hybrid](http://www.slideshare.net/iolo/hybrid-mobile-application-framework) Mobile Application Framework.